# Помогите составить уравнение на python

Tags: python, match

Напиши программу, которая вычисляет значение функции
f(a, b) = 7(a + b)<sup>3</sup> – 5a<sup>2</sup> + 3b – 1
по введённым целым значениям a и b.

Пример 1: Пользователь ввёл:
1
2
программа выводит 189

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = 7*(a+b)**3
x = (-5*a)**2
z = 3*b
v = -1
print(с-x+z+v)
```

У меня постоянно 169, не могу понять как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас три ошибки:

- в квадрат нужно возводить только `a`, а не `-5*a`
- все слагаемые нужно складывать, а вы второе вычитаете, думаю, это вы пытались так компенсировать первую ошибку
- у вас в итоговой формуле буква `c` русская, при исполнении кода будет ошибка

Итого, исправленный код, дающий правильный ответ:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = 7*(a+b)**3
x = -5*a**2    # <-- эта строка исправлена
z = 3*b
v = -1
print(c+x+z+v) # <-- и эта исправлена
```

Answer (score 0):

На мой субъективный взгляд, формула выглядит понятнее в одну строку - как приведено в задании. И вроде бы в задании же надо это оформить как функцию `f(a,b)`.

```
def f(a, b):
    return 7 * (a + b) ** 3 - 5 * a ** 2 + 3 * b - 1


a, b = int(input('a: ')), int(input('b: '))
value = f(a, b)
print(value)
```

```
a: 1
b: 2
189
```